# Dash+plotly+bootstrap help needed, arranging custom headers/labels to graph

Tags: python, css, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I'd like to know how to get 10 headers spaced out evenly over a bootstrap column, the goal is to align them with the bars in my bar graph in the row/column above. I don't even know how to google for this, where should i start?

So it's kind of open ended question, is this something i could easily accomplish with CSS formatting on the headers ?(html.h1()) ? is there a way i can add spacing between headers based on screen size? like px vs. em etc...  or should I dive deep into building my graph objects in plotly and making some custom label somehow.

So to re-iterate - the '12345678910' are on a seperate bootstrap row/column below the graph. I want each of the 10 headers to align centered with the 10 bars so i can create a custom data readout.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you're looking for, by adding the below snippet in your `assets/style.css`:

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 25px;
  }

.alignCards {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 86%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.cardBorders {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

and in your dash element, you need to add the classes you just created:

```
html.Div([html.Div(html.H1(n), className="cardBorders") for n in range(10)], 
                 className="grid alignCards")
```

Below is the full code that you can use to test:

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
import random
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict([{"x":val, "y":random.random()} for val in range(10)])


app = Dash(__name__)


app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(figure=px.bar(df, x="x", y="y")),
        
        html.Div([html.Div(html.H1(n), className="cardBorders")for n in range(10)], 
                 className="grid alignCards"),
    ]
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

PS: Try to limit your container size to a specific width, and once it's done, will become easier to find the correct value to align the bars and the cards

[image]

I hope it can solve your problem, and if the answer was helpful, please, don't forget to vote up and flag it as the answer!

Regards,
Leonardo

Comment: Can't thank you enough! this is exactly what i was looking for. I don't quite understand enough css to get what's going on here but I will soon, this would have taken a long time for me to google my way through.

Comment: Cool.... @PhilipC. I would like to recommend you a great course I know which has some CSS and UI fundamental courses for free -> https://scrimba.com/

Comment: I notice you assign 'cardBorders' to each of the .Div in the for loop , but I don't see cardBorders defined in your style.css ? I only see .grid and .alignCards

Comment: Hey @PhilipC., I have updated my answer and added the class you did mention